# Excel VBA to match and line up rows

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have an Excel document with columns A to J. I have columns K to N with related data, but not aligned.

I need to match value from value in column F with value in column K so they are lined up. When I shift K, I have to shift L, M, N together.

I cannot sort columns A to J - they must remain in place.

**Example before:**

```
A     B     C     D     E     F        G     H     I     J     K       L     M     N

data  data  data  data  data  record1  data  data  data  data  record3 data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  record2  data  data  data  data  record1 data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  record3  data  data  data  data  

data  data  data  data  data  record4  data  data  data  data
```

**Example after:**

```
A     B     C     D     E     F        G     H     I     J     K       L     M     N

data  data  data  data  data  record1  data  data  data  data  record1 data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  record2  data  data  data  data  

data  data  data  data  data  record3  data  data  data  data  record3 data  data  data

data  data  data  data  data  record4  data  data  data  data
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would probably be ADO.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
''you want, but it is very convenient for notes
''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
''can be used.
''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT * " _
       & "FROM [Sheet2$A1:J5] a " _
       & "LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$K1:N5] b " _
       & "ON a.F=b.k "

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3


''Pick a suitable empty worksheet for the results

Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

''Tidy up
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi all, this is great I think I would try ADO, I have to do it trough the code since I have some stuff prior to this (populating values in K-N). Just one question for Remou, I never know number of rows, so I cannot use "Sheet2$A1:J5" and "Sheet2$K1:N5" it is more than 5 rows, and it would change from time to time. How I can specify as many records as there are instead of 5 (something like "recordCount"). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a column reference `[Sheet2$A:J]` or a named range `& "FROM ANamedRange a "`

Comment: Hi Remou, I tried your code and I am getting error on "rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3" debugger is throwing me "no value given for one or more required parameters". Code is the same only change I did is "Sheet2$A1:J5" (and for "K-N") to "Sheet1$A1:J10". Thanks

Comment: Do you have headings on your columns? If so, you should use the column headings here: `a.F=b.k`, where F= name of column with record set 1 key and k=record set 2 key, if not, you must change the connection string to show HDR=No and use F1,F2,F3 etc for the column names, which would give `a.F6=b.F11`

Comment: Hi Remou, I have headings for A to J, but not for K to N. So I changed code and I am getting the same error. Here is exactly what I am using: strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    cn.Open strCon
    strSQL = "SELECT * " _
           & "FROM [Sheet1$A:J] a " _
           & "LEFT JOIN [Sheet1$K:N] b " _
           & "ON a.F6=b.F11 "
    rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

Comment: oops. I forgot to start counting again from 1 for recordset 2: `ON a.F6=b.F1` You will need to select a range for the first recordset that does not include headings, because you have HDR=No.

Comment: extraordinary :) thanks so much it worked like charm :). I am really appreciating. I have one more really small question for you. In column "K" values are hyper linked, so when data is sorted in "Sheet3" I lost hyperlinks. Do you maybe know how I can keep them. Thanks again

Comment: Not at the moment, but I will think about it.

Comment: I just wonder: with the above procedure, you read the "saved" data, right ? So, if the data has changed in the workbook since last saved, the query will not see those changes ?

Comment: I tested: how comes that it works on live data ? I mean, if the data has changed in the workbook since last saved, the query seems to return the latest values. I am was expecting the opposite: query would return last SAVED data...

Comment: @iDevlop You have got me too early in the morning. I remember testing before, it uses live data. I am not sure what the problem is?

Comment: @Remou: no problem, just an excellent surprise ! Thx, have a coffee ;-)

Comment: @Remou : is it possible to use particular required column names in the Query ? and i also require where condition to filter.

Comment: @logan You can use pretty much any valid Jet/ACE SQL. The column names depend on the range and connection string (HDR= ...). If the column names are not valid for the connection, they may be replace with F<number>

Comment: @Remou : You are expertise, Sorry i can not understand. Any link to understand ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Sort columns K - M and move them further away (like in X-Z)

In columns K-M add a `VLOOKUP()` function to pull data from X-Z based on column F.

To make it pretty pull out the row# with the `INDEX()` function and only if found copy the data from X-Z to K-L with the `MATCH()` function. Otherwise return an empty string.

Columns A-J with data, with column F containing the lookup values

Column  X-Z with reference table with X containing the loopup match values

Add a column N with `=MATCH((Value in F),(XYZ Table),FALSE)`
  this produces either a `#N/A` or a row number

Column K with `=IF( NOT( ISNA(Value in N) ), INDEX((X Table), (Value in N) ), "")`

Column L with `=IF( NOT( ISNA(Value in N) ), INDEX((Y Table), (Value in N) ), "")`

Column M with `=IF( NOT( ISNA(Value in N) ), INDEX((Z Table), (Value in N) ), "")`

Unless you want to do it in VBA, this works.