# How to match 2 columns in excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet, sheet1 which has 2 cols, A and B. Col A has some values and has corresponding mapping in col B(not all values in A have a mapping in B, some are empty). The sorting is done from Z-A and w.r.to Col A. I have another excel sheet, sheet2 which has similar Col A and Col B. Now, i want to find out whether any match is there between Col A of sheet1 and Col A of sheet2. If matches are found, those values should be copied onto a new column.

Comment: Which values do you want copied into a new column? The values that match in column A on both sheets or the values in column B if there is match in column A on both sheets?

Answer (score 2):

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!L24,E24:F27,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I might give a better explanation because i didn't feel any of these were useful for me to personally figure out `VLOOKUP` and this answer came up high on list of google when looking for `VLOOKUP` Examples.

Here is my example which is looking up data from one worksheet to another:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet1!$A$2:$Q$338,2,FALSE)
```

which is:

```
=VLOOKUP(<NEEDLE>,<HAYSTACK>,<COLUMN OF HAYSTACK TO PULL BACK INTO LOOKUP COLUMN>,<LEAVE AS FALSE>)
```

Steps:

- Select the column which is looked up as the `<NEEDLE>` eg `lookup_value` . This might be a list of cars
- Then select the entire range of the data you want to search within as `<HAYSTACK>` eg `table_array`. This is simply a selection of a range of which data to search through. It can be range within the current `worksheet`, or a range on a different `tab/worksheet`
- give a number which is index of column in the `Haystack` of which column you would like returned as the value. eg `col_index_num`
- supply "false" as final paramater. this should always be false at least in the cases I've used it.

I hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do a lot with Excel and ADO: [Excel VBA to match and line up rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-match-and-lineup-rows/4381166#4381166)