# How to get uncommon elements in two lists in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

In excel i have two lists A and B of names. I want to get list C that contains uncommon elements in A and B.

How can i do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/81498/excel-find-items-in-one-column-that-are-not-in-another-column

Comment: You can do a lot with ADO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-match-and-lineup-rows/4381166#4381166

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tricky but you can use the VLOOKUP function.

http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/learning_vlookup_in_excel has a decent explanation for its use.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out by inverting the solution for finding common values given on this page: 
[How to find common values from two lists](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/02/13/how-to-find-common-values-from-two-lists/)

It works as an array function, so you have to press ctrl + shift + enter after you enter it. The advantage of doing it as an array function is it doesn't leave a bunch of spaces to be edited out. All the relevant values are at the top.

I have a list of 40 reference values in Column A, I enter a list of 7 unknown values to compare in Column B, and I want to get a list in Column C showing the values in Column B that are NOT in Column A.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$40,$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW($B$2:$B$7)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$7))+1),ROW(B1)))
```

The COUNTIF statement generates an array of 1s and 0s, depending on whether the value in Column B is in Column A (1 if yes, 0 if no). 
Since I'm looking for uncommon values, I have the IF statement return an array of row values corresponding to values in B that aren't in A. The ~Row-Min(Row)+1 bit makes sure you're using the right row value. 
SMALL returns the ROW(B1)-smallest (like 1st smallest, or 4th smallest) from the array returned by the IF statement. So now I've got a single value instead of an array. 
INDEX returns the value of the row in Column B. 
Remember to press ctrl + shift + enter.