# Calculate the difference between two non-adjacent columns, based on a "match column" using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for the most efficient way to compare two sets of two columns, thus:

Set 1:

`A | B  | C |

11_22 | 10 |   |

33_44 | 20 |   |

55_66 | 30 |   |

77_88 | 40 |   |

99_00 | 50 |   |`

Set 2:

`J     | K  |

33_44 | 19 |

99_00 | 47 |

77_88 | 40 |`

For each match between column A and J, column C should display the difference between the adjacent cells 
(in this case 33_44, 99_00, and 77_88) in B and K, respectively, with the full
amount in column B if no match exists in J

`A     | B  | C

11_22 | 10 | 10

33_44 | 20 | 1

55_66 | 30 | 30

77_88 | 40 | 0

99_00 | 50 | 3`

I'm thinking of creating two multi-dimensional arrays containing values
in the ranges (A, B) and (J, K), with a nested loop, but am not sure how to
get the result back into column C when a match occurs. Creating a third "result array" and outputting that on a fresh sheet would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do a lot with ADO, for example: [Excel VBA to match and line up rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-match-and-lineup-rows/4381166#4381166)