# Matching difficulty from 2 different worksheets of repetitive values

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following case:

Worksheet2:
I have 3 columns in Worksheet2

1. Sales Account Name
2. Sales Rep No.
3. Sales Level 6 Name

Worksheet1:

I have 3 columns in worsheet1

1. ERP/Segment1
2. Misc6
3. Misc7

My aim here is to read each line from worksheet1 and look for matching values from ERP/Segment1 matching Sales Account Name from worsheet2 and insert the  Sales Level 6 Name in Misc6.  Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to read [Excel VBA to match and line up rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-match-and-lineup-rows/4381166#4381166)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a VLookup - Do you need to insert multiple Sales Account names into the Misc6 column?

Can you post an example of your data?