# Best method of Excel Data Comparison present in 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel macro to match and lineup rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-to-match-and-lineup-rows)

I have an Excel workbook with 2 Sheets with same set of columns but data arranged in different way. I need to compare Sheet 2 against Sheet 1 with the use of one or more Key column and identify unmatched records.

**Data in sheet1:**

```
UserId Name Salary DeptId DeptName Location
1      Loga 2000   1      HR       Chennai
2      Mano 1500   2      PM       Mumbai
3      Raj  2500   5      GM       Delhi
```

**Data in sheet1:**

```
UserId Name Salary DeptId DeptName Location
2      Mano 1500   2      PM       Mumbai
3      Raj  2500   5      GM       Delhi
```

first I need to match records based on UserId and DeptId, if matches in both the sheet Compare Salary  -> if salary matches store the record with UserId as Salary Matched.
Similarly if UserId and DeptId matches in both the sheet then compare location -> if matches then store record with userid as location matched if not report as particular UserID not matched.,

I am planning to use HLookUp in VBA Macro for comparing but seems lengthy process when no.of rows increases and reduces performance as well. 
is there any suggestion available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a method that i use always, its hard-coded you can optimize it according to your example.
Sub findMatch()

```
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim UserID As Integer
  Dim UserID2 As Integer
  Dim DeptID As Integer
  Dim DeptID2 As Integer
  Dim sal As Integer
  Dim Salary2 As Integer
  Dim Location As String
  Dim Location2 As String

  Dim rows1 as Integer
  Dim rows2 as Integer

  rows1=Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'rows count in sheet1
  rows2=Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'rows count in sheet2

    For i = 1 To rows1
        UserID = Workbooks("yourWorkBook").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value)
        'yourWorkBook is the name of the Access document
        DeptID = Workbooks("yourWorkBook").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value)
        Salary = Workbooks("yourWorkBook").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "C").Value)
        Location  = Workbooks("yourWorkBook").Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "F").Value)

        for j= 1 to rows2
            UserID2 = Workbooks("yourWorkBook").Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, "A").Value)
            DeptID2 = Workbooks("yourWorkBook").Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, "D").Value)
            Salary2 = Workbooks("yourWorkBook").Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, "C").Value)
            Location2 = Workbooks("yourWorkBook").Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, "F").Value)

            If (UserID=UserID2) and (DeptID=DeptID2) Then

                If Salary=Salary2 then 'userID, DeptID and Salary match
                    'you create manually another sheet (sheet3) in wich you will store the desired data
                    lstSalRow = Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Getting the count of rows in the sheet
                    'inserting after the last row
                    Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(lstSalRow+1, "A").Value=UserID  'Storing UserID
                    Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(lstSalRow+1, "B").Value=Salary  'Storing salary

                Elseif strcmp(Location, Location2)=0 then  'userID, deptID and Location match

                    'Location matched : you can create another sheet (sheet4) in wich you will store the desired data
                    lstLocRow = Worksheets("sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    Worksheets("sheet4").Cells(lstLocRow+1, "A").Value=UserID 
                    Worksheets("sheet4").Cells(lstLocRow+1, "B").Value=Location

                Else 'only userID and DeptID match
                    'do other actions
                End If

            End If

        next j

    next i

End Sub
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple solutions. The easiest but not cleanest solution is to create a key using UserId and Dept-Id. A simple concatenation would do the job. For example, adding a G column (assuming UserId is in A and so on..) you could do: `=$A2 & "-" & $D2` Then use a simple lookup function to see if that unique ID you created is present in both sheets, for example : `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($G2, Sheet2!$G$2:$G$3, 1, 0)), 0, 1)` (sorry if the function names are incorrect, I am translating from french). Then do whatever you want with this data.

Comment: I wanted to do this in VBA. and No.of key columns may vary it depends on data. Whatever given is just an example.