# Combing Tables in Excel using VBA and ADODB

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

Using Excel VBA I would like to be able to combine two tables in excel with a common key. I have suggested ADODB as a method,but am open to any other more efficient/elegant methods. Please see below for a minimal example:

I have the below to start with...

Sheet1

```
    A     B       C
 1 type year1   year2
 2 aaa  100     110
 3 bbb  220     240
 4 ccc  304     200
 5 ddd  20      30
 6 eee  440     20
```

Sheet2

```
    A     B       C
 1 type year1   year2
 2 bbb  10      76
 3 ccc  44      39
 4 ddd  50      29
 5 eee  22      23
 6 fff  45      55
```

And would like to combine it so that I have the following as a result:

Sheet3

```
    A     B       C       D       E
 1 type year1   year2   year1   year2
 2 aaa  100      110      0       0
 3 bbb  220      240      10      76
 4 ccc  304      200      44      39
 5 ddd  20       30       50      29
 6 eee  440      20       22      23
 7 fff  0        0        45      55
```

Have done a bit of googling and SQL type outer joins seems close but not sure how to implement it.

Below is the code used to try and implement it so far...

```
Option Explicit



Sub JoinTables()

 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection


 With cn
     .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
     .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
         "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
     .Open
 End With

 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

 rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] OUTER JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet1$].[type] = " & _
     "[Sheet2$].[type]", cn

 With Worksheets("Sheet3")
     .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
 End With

 rs.Close
 cn.Close

 End Sub
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379213/excel-macro-to-match-and-lineup-rows/4381166#4381166

Comment: @Fionnuala as far as i remember ADODB didn't support an outer join so that link to your answer doesn't really help here

Comment: @vba4all ADODB with Jet or ACE drivers supports nearly anything that MS Access SQL supports, this includes Outer Joins. It has done for a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

So JET does not support full outer joins so I ended up having to rewrite it using a left join and then a right join to check for types we missed:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
 Set cn = New ADODB.Connection


 With cn
     .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
     .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
         "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"
     .Open
 End With

 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset



  rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].[Type] AS Type" & _
  " ,[Sheet1$].[Year1] as Year11" & _
  " ,[Sheet1$].[Year2] as Year21" & _
  " ,[Sheet2$].[Year1] as Year12" & _
  " ,[Sheet2$].[Year2] as Year22" & _
  " FROM [Sheet1$] LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet1$].[type] = " & _
     "[Sheet2$].[type] UNION ALL " & _
     " SELECT [Sheet2$].[Type] AS Type" & _
  " ,[Sheet1$].[Year1] as Year11" & _
  " ,[Sheet1$].[Year2] as Year21" & _
  " ,[Sheet2$].[Year1] as Year12" & _
  " ,[Sheet2$].[Year2] as Year22" & _
  " FROM [Sheet1$] RIGHT JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet1$].[type] = " & _
 "[Sheet2$].[type] WHERE [Sheet2$].[type] NOT IN (SELECT type FROM [Sheet1$]) ", cn

 With Worksheets("Sheet3")
     .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
 End With


 rs.Close
 cn.Close

End Sub
```

The flow is like this:

1. Get matches between Sheet1 and Sheet2
2. Get matches between Sheet2 and Sheet1 that we didn't get in the previous query

Let me know if you have any questions or if I missed anything.

Edited the query: I realized did not need the third step and it was excessive.